# Does "IOC container" just maintain dependencies?

Tags: javascript, c, spring, design-patterns, ioc-container

As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection),

> A **dependency** is an object that can be used (as a service).

---

[Image processing](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/tree/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3) application is the OOP paradigm style C syntax that address 4 roles, shown below.

## 1) interface (`handlers.h`)

```
typedef struct {
    int (*canHandle) (char *);
    int (*drawImage)(char *);
    int (*savefile)(char *);
}imageHandler;
```

---

## 2) Take one Dependency (`gifhandler.c`)

```
imageHandler gifhandler = {
    gif_canHandle,
    gif_drawImage,
    gif_savefile
};
```

---

## 3) Dependency container (dealt by `config.c`)

```
//gifhandler.c - dependency 
int _init(){
    printf(" registering gifhandler \n");
    reg_handler(&gifhandler);
    return 0;
}

//config.c
imageHandler *imagehandlers[10];
int reg_handler(imageHandler *ih){
// we need to perform checks here.
    imagehandlers[libs] = ih;
    libs++;
    return TRUE;
}
// config.c
int init_handlers(){
    .....
    soptr = dlopen(so_name,RTLD_NOW);
    ....
}
```

---

## 4) Client - Service locator (`UI.C`)

```
// UI.C
switch(choice){
        case 1:
            vdrawImage(filename);   
            break;
        case 2:
            vsavefile(filename);
            break;
}
// viml.c
int vdrawImage(char *filename){
    ...
    handleno = find_handler(filename);
    ...
    ih=imagehandlers[handleno];
    ih->drawImage(filename);    
    return FALSE;       
}
// viml.c
int vsavefile(char *newfilename ){
    ...
    handleno = find_handler(newfilename);
    ...
    ih=imagehandlers[handleno];
    ih->savefile(newfilename); 
}
```

---

1) To add new dependency(`libxyzhandl.so.1`) in Dependency container, it just requires adding a new entry in `config.txt` **configurable**, as shown below,

> **config.txt**
>
> `./libgifhandl.so.1`
>
> `./libtiffhandl.so.1`

2) New service provided by `./libxyzhandl.so.1`, will be contained by Dependency container  **without re-compilation** of application.

3) Testing of complete application is **not required**, except source code of `libxyzhandl.so`.

So, if `config.txt` goes empty, then, application does nothing, except saying, `We cannot handle this kind of files`, shown [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/blob/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3/VIML.C#L25), for any input(image file).

Below is a visualisation of call flow,

### [image]

**Question:**

1) Is *dependency container* different from an *IOC container*?

2) Does *Spring IOC container* provide more functionality than just maintaining dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

These are basically the same thing. People tend to use them interchangeably. You can find a nice explanation [here](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/what-is-ioc-container-or-di-container) and [here](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/understanding-inversion-of-control-dependency-injection-and-service-locator).
The implementation you've shown allows for a simple runtime-injection of depenencies, but so-called *IoC containers* like Spring contexts are no different.

Comment: 1) But in my code, finding dependency is done using service locator but not DI. 2) Am saying that my code as IOC container, because, before user gives any input to locate and avail service, we maintain all the dependencies configured in `config.txt`

Comment: I think you've combined these two approaches - your service locator uses DI container to resolve dependencies and then pass them to your app.

Comment: So, Can I call this code that provides IOC container and also implements service locator pattern to locate the service from the container?